# Как вывести изображение, созданное с помощью PHP, в тег <img>

Tags: php

У меня есть файл index.php и img.php.
**index.php:**

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Показать диаграмму">
    </form>
    <?php
    include "img.php";
    ?>
    <img src="<?= $_GET['picture'] ?>" alt="">
</body>

</html>
```

**img.php:**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // Диаграмма будет представлена для значений следующего массива:
    $values = array(
        "23", "32", "35", "57", "12",
        "3", "36", "54", "32", "15",
        "43", "24", "30"
    );
    // Количество столбцов диаграммы:
    $columns = count($values);
    // Задаем щирину и высоту всего изображения
    $width = 300;
    $height = 200;
    // Задаем пространство между колонками:
    $padding = 2;
    // Получаем ширину одной колонки:
    $column_width = $width / $columns;
    // Создаем переменные
    $im = imagecreate($width, $height);
    $gray = imagecolorallocate($im, 0xcc, 0xcc, 0xcc);
    $gray_lite = imagecolorallocate($im, 0xee, 0xee, 0xee);
    $gray_dark = imagecolorallocate($im, 0x7f, 0x7f, 0x7f);
    $white = imagecolorallocate($im, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff);
    // Заполняем фон картинки
    imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, $width, $height, $white);
    $maxv = 0;
    // Вычисляем максимум
    for ($i = 0; $i < $columns; $i++)
        $maxv = max($values[$i], $maxv);
    // Рисуем каждую колонку
    for ($i = 0; $i < $columns; $i++) {
        $column_height = ($height / 100) * (($values[$i] / $maxv) * 100);
        $x1 = $i * $column_width;
        $y1 = $height - $column_height;
        $x2 = (($i + 1) * $column_width) - $padding;
        $y2 = $height;
        imagefilledrectangle($im, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $gray);
        //для 3D эффекта
        imageline($im, $x1, $y1, $x1, $y2, $gray_lite);
        imageline($im, $x1, $y2, $x2, $y2, $gray_lite);
        imageline($im, $x2, $y1, $x2, $y2, $gray_dark);
    }
    header("Location:index.php?picture="."im.png");
    ob_end_flush();
    imagepng($im);
}
```

Так я создал некоторое изображение с помощью PHP. Я хочу вывести это изображение в тег , который находится в index.php. Как мне передать из img.php  в  index.html это изображение. Я не хочу, чтобы изображение было на весь экран браузера - я именно хочу в тег  поместить его, чтобы не на весь экран оно было.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В img.php прописываем

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

это будет отдавать изображение, как ответ на вызов

а в коде страницы в качестве источника изображения прописываем вызов img.php

```
<img src="img.php" alt="">
```

Comment: У меня отображается на весь экран в таком случае

Comment: а у меня нет. как обустрою размеры img, так и получается - как если любой png вывести

Comment: А может это быть из-за настроек php.ini?

Comment: во-1х, вы location убрали? во-2х,  добавьте, например, width `<img src="img.php" width="100">` - меняется же размер?

Comment: Всё, я разобрался. Дело было в том, что я не убрал include img.php Спасибо за помощь. Помогли) А я вам поставил репутацию или как оно там называется? Просто я новичок на сайте

Comment: слева от ответа нажмите на галку

Comment: Вверх или вниз?

Comment: А-а-а. Галочку?

Comment: все ок. для вверх у вас наверное еще репутации мало :)  но когда будет, не забывайте нажимать :)